# Monodb database migration with embedded query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Currently in my database I have `messages` objects set up as the following.

```
{
    "name" : "System",
    "message" : "Sean Callahan has entered the room.",
    "time" : 1406479167270,
    "type" : "system_message",
    "room" : "helloroom",
    "_id" : "4yeHzhHAQmGJNtHww"
}
```

I want to basically migrate my data so that every message has a `roomId` that point it at the appropriate room. Currently this is done by the with the `room` attribute, which I know see the fault in my ways for various reasons.

My room objects are setup something like this.

```
{
    "_id:" xxxxxxxxx
    "room_name:" "testingroom"
}
```

So I was hoping there was a way to run a one-liner that would just add the correct `roomId` to every current message based on the current `room` attribute that is set

I was thinking something along the lines of..

`db.messages.update({}, {$set: {roomId: db.rooms.findOne({room_name: room})._id}})`

As of now, I am getting room is not defined, which makes perfect sense. But I can't seem to get it right, and this may just not be possible in a one-line query.

Answer (score 0):

As you discovered, this isn't possible in a one-line query since you need to join data from two collections.

Here's an example of how to add the missing field in the `mongo` shell:

```
db.messages.find(
    { roomId: { $exists: false} }
).forEach(function(room) {
    var roomId = db.rooms.findOne({room_name: room.room});
    if (roomId._id) {
        db.messages.update(
            { _id: room._id },
            { $set: { roomId: roomId._id }}
        )
    }
})
```

You could tidy this up with some error checking, and for updates on a large collection consider using the [Bulk Update API](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/js-bulk/) (only available in MongoDB 2.6+).